# MySQL: Replace numbers digits to Zero

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to replace all number's digits to "0" but keep only first digit:

Sample convert:

```
`3849` => `3000`
`3001` => `3000`
`3838383838` => `3000000000`
```

and apply this on mysql column?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One straightforward option is to concatenate together the first digit with a sequence of zeroes whose length is one less than the length of the number.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(LEFT(col, 1), REPEAT('0', CHAR_LENGTH(col) - 1)) AS new_col
FROM yourTable
```

Note that if `col` be a numeric type column, then technically we should be casting it to text before taking a substring.  In this case, MySQL would do an implicit conversion to text, so technically we don't need a formal cast, though this point should be made.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Instead of `CONCAT(LEFT(col, 1), REPEAT('0', CHAR_LENGTH(col) - 1))`, you can do `RPAD(LEFT(col, 1), '0', CHAR_LENGTH(col))`.

Answer (score 3):

hope this work for you

```
 select left(column_name,1),
    rpad(left(column_name,1),length(column_name),'0')
    from table_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a C language style approach. Floor(3456/1000) gives us 3 (like an integer division), and just multiply with 1000 to get the result.

```
 SELECT floor(3456 / power(10, length(3456)-1)) * power(10, length(3456)-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

[TRUNCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) with a negative second argument will set digits to the left of the decimal point to zero:

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(column_name, -FLOOR(LOG10(column_name)))
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Another good option +1.  [Tested and functioning](http://rextester.com/MHJJL72484).

Answer (score 1):

```
select floor(n / POW(10, floor(LOG10(n)))) * POW(10, floor(LOG10(n))) from t
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=cd0cad13ca625b6102b6aa2da6174c78)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT left(columnname,1), rpad(left(columnname,1),length(columnname),'0') FROM tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like this:-

```
select Column1-convert(bigint, (SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(20),Column1),2,len(convert(varchar(20),Column1))))) ,* 
from yourtable
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for MYSql:

```
 DECLARE v_test NVARCHAR(100)
SET v_test = '585623658'
SELECT LEFT(v_test,1) + REPLICATE(0,(CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(v_test)) - 1)) AS Colum
```

Comment: This is SQL Server code.  The question is tagged for MySQL.